# Error with Class in C++ for my project

Tags: c++, class

I am new to this. Basically I just learnt how to use class in C++. When I try to print out, the values just seem to be 0. Can anyone help me out? Its supposed to print out:

Susan Myers   47899    Accounting     Vice President
Mark Jones    39119    IT             Position
Joy Rogers    81774    Manufacturing  Engineer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Employee
{
    private:
        string name; 
        int idNumber; 
        string department; 
        string position; 

    public:
        Employee()
        {
            name=" "; 
            idNumber=0; 
            department=" "; 
            position=" "; 
        }

        Employee(string, int, string, string)
        {
            int id; 
            string n,d,p; 

            name=n; 
            idNumber=id; 
            department=d; 
            position=p; 
        }

        Employee(string, int)
        {
            string n; 
            int id; 

            name=n; 
            idNumber=id; 
        }
    void setName(string)
    {
        string n; 
        name=n; 
    }
    void setId(int)
    {
        int id;
        idNumber=id; 
    }
    void setDepartment(string)
    {
        string d; 
        department=d; 
    }
    void setPosition(string)
    {
        string p; 
        position=p; 
    }
    string getName() const
    {
        return name; 
    }
    int getId() const
    {
        return idNumber; 
    }
    string getDepartment() const
    {
        return department; 
    }
    string getPosition() const
    {
        return position; 
    }

}; 


int main()
{

    Employee e1; 
    Employee e2; 
    Employee e3; 

    e1.setName("Susan Meyers"); 
    e2.setName("Mark Jones"); 
    e3.setName("Joy Rogers"); 


    e1.setId(47899); 
    e2.setId(39119); 
    e3.setId(81744); 

    e1.setDepartment("Accounting"); 
    e2.setDepartment("IT"); 
    e3.setDepartment("Manufacturing"); 

    e1.setPosition("Vice President"); 
    e2.setPosition("Programmer"); 
    e3.setPosition("Engineer"); 

    cout<<"---------------------------------------"<<endl; 
    cout<<"Name"<<setw(6)<<"ID Number"<<setw(10)<<"Department"<<setw(12)<<"Position"<<endl; 

    cout<<e1.getName()<<setw(6)<<e1.getId()<<setw(10)<<e1.getDepartment()<<setw(12)<<e1.getDepartment()<<endl; 
    cout<<e2.getName()<<setw(6)<<e2.getId()<<setw(10)<<e2.getDepartment()<<setw(12)<<e2.getDepartment()<<endl; 
    cout<<e3.getName()<<setw(6)<<e3.getId()<<setw(10)<<e3.getDepartment()<<setw(12)<<e3.getDepartment()<<endl; 


    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Why not re-read the book? Parameters usually have names

Comment: I think you should throw what you have into the bin and read [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/5958455)

Answer (score 4):

This is what you get when you rely on guesswork rather than properly reading an introductory textbook on C++

A constructor of the `Employee` class which (apart from a blank line that I've removed) you define as

> ```
> Employee(string, int, string, string)
>   {
>         int id; 
>         string n,d,p; 
>         name=n; 
>         idNumber=id; 
>         department=d; 
>         position=p; 
>   }
> ```

has the following effects.

- The four arguments passed by the caller are ignored, since they are not named.
- Four default-initialised variables (`id`, `n`, `d`, and `p`) are defined local to the constructor body.   `id` will be uninitialised.   The others, since they are `std::string`, are default-initialised (to an empty string)
- The next four statements copy those variables into class members.   The result is that initialising `idNumber` has undefined behaviour (since `id` is uninitialised) and the three strings are initialised to empty strings.

To get the effect that (I assume) you intend, change this to;

```
Employee(std::string n, int id, std::string d, std::string p)
{
    name=n; 
    idNumber=id; 
    department=d; 
    position=p; 
}
```

Note that I'm calling `string` by its full name `std::string`.  That allows removing the `using namespace std` which (among other things) is BAD practice in header files.

Even better, change this to

```
Employee(const std::string &n, int id, const std::string &d, const std::string &p) : 
     name(n), idNumber(id), department(d), position(p)
{
}
```

which passes the strings by `const` reference (avoids additional copies of `std::string`s) and uses an initialiser list instead of assigning to members in the constructor.

Similar comments apply to ALL of the member functions of `Employee`, except that only constructors can have initialiser lists.

Answer (score 0):

## Errors made

1. Presentation

Your code is extremely cluttered, and has much irrelevant stuff.

2. Syntax

void setPosition(string){
Here your function has no argument!  What is string?

## Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
class Employee{
    public:
        string name; 
        int idNumber; 
        string department; 
        string position; 

    void setName(string n){ 
        name=n; 
    }
    void setId(int k){
        int id;
        idNumber=id; 
    }
    void setDepartment(string d){
        department=d; 
    }
    void setPosition(string p){
        position=p; 
    }
    string getName(){
        return name; 
    }
    int getId(){
        return idNumber; 
    }
    string getDepartment(){
        return department; 
    }
    string getPosition(){
        return position; 
    }
}; 
int main(){
    Employee e1; 
    Employee e2; 
    Employee e3; 
    e1.setName("Susan Meyers"); 
    e2.setName("Mark Jones"); 
    e3.setName("Joy Rogers"); 
    e1.setId(47899); 
    e2.setId(39119); 
    e3.setId(81744); 
    e1.setDepartment("Accounting"); 
    e2.setDepartment("IT"); 
    e3.setDepartment("Manufacturing"); 
    e1.setPosition("Vice President"); 
    e2.setPosition("Programmer"); 
    e3.setPosition("Engineer"); 
    cout<<"---------------------------------------"<<endl; 
    cout<<"Name"<<" "<<"ID Number"<<" "<<"Department"<<" "<<"Position"<<endl; 
    cout<<e1.getName()<<" "<<e1.getId()<<" "<<e1.getDepartment()<<" "<<e1.getPosition()<<endl; 
    cout<<e2.getName()<<" "<<e2.getId()<<" "<<e2.getDepartment()<<" "<<e2.getPosition()<<endl; 
    cout<<e3.getName()<<" "<<e3.getId()<<" "<<e3.getDepartment()<<" "<<e3.getPosition()<<endl; 
}
```

## Output

```
---------------------------------------
Name ID Number Department Position
Susan Meyers 32767 Accounting Vice President
Mark Jones 32767 IT Programmer
Joy Rogers 32767 Manufacturing Engineer
```

## Explanation

I have shortened your code by 50%(shows how much redundant stuff you had), and here is a working code.

```
void setDepartment(string d){
     department=d; 
}
```

Here, string d is defined IN the function as an argument.  Note that your code also cout<< department twice, and I have corrected that for you in my above code.
Hope this helps.